# Local/Global Boolean problem

Tags: c++, programming-languages

I have a `Doughnut` class, with an `eaten` boolean field. I need to make the boolean a global variable for it to work, but it needs to to be local so I can make many `Doughnut` instances, where some are "eaten" and some are not. I want the doughnut to graphically disappear when it has been eaten

The problem with setting it global is all my doughnuts will be flagged "eaten" upon one being eaten, and if it's local it will not disappear when eaten. How can I fix this?

Comment: If this is supposed to be a joke, I don't get it.

Comment: i think your question should be better rephrased...

Comment: He's making a game where you eat donuts. The donut object needs to have a `IsEaten` flag. But for some reason he can't get it to work; he can only figure out how to deal with global variables. Poorly described question.

Comment: is anyone else getting hungry by reading this question?

Comment: I do)))) I have even posted a few lines of code, now I'm realty hungry)))

Answer (score 7):

Have a boolean per a doughnut.

If you have a doughnut class, add a member flag:

```
class Doughnut
{
   bool m_bEaten;
};
```

Or probably you don't want to store the information in doughnut, so you can have a mapping ;)

```
std::map<Doughnut, bool> Doughnuts;
```

But then you'll need to implement operator< for the Doughnut :)

Or, if you know you have 10 doughnuts you can have a static array to hold the flags which doughnut is eaten:

```
bool eatenDoughnuts[10]; // Initialize properly.

// Eat any doughnut you like:
eatenDoughnuts[2] = true;

// Check if you have eaten doughnut number 2:
if(eatenDoughnuts[2])
{
    // Pure doughnut number 2.
}
```

Or, if you don't know the number of doughnuts at compile time use dynamic container:

```
std::vector<bool> atenDoughnuts;
```

Or, use template meta-programing to eat your doughnuts compile time ;)

Yet, the question is edited, so we are sure you have a doughnut class. So here it goes:

```
#include <vector>

class Doughnut
{
public:
   enum Kind {VANILLA, CHOCOLATE}; // The kind of your doughnut.

   Doughnut(Kind k = VANILLA) // VANILLA is the default.
      : kind(k), eaten(false) {}

   void eat() { eaten = true; } // We luv eating doughnuts.
   bool isEaten() { return eaten; }

private:
   Kind kind;  // The kind of your doughnut.
   bool eaten; // Has anyone eaten it yet?
};

int main()
{
   // Your delicious doughnuts package :)
   std::vector<Doughnut> deliciousDoughnuts;

   // Go buy some delicious doughnuts.
   deliciousDoughnuts.push_back(Doughnut(Doughnut::VANILLA));
   deliciousDoughnuts.push_back(Doughnut(Doughnut::CHOCOLATE));
   deliciousDoughnuts.push_back(Doughnut(Doughnut::VANILLA));

   // You love delicious chocolate doughnut? EAT IT!
   deliciousDoughnuts[1].eat();

   // Check have you drooped it down or you are good!
   if(deliciousDoughnuts[1].isEaten())
   {
      // Poor chocolate doughnut...
   }
}
```

I'm kinda kind today ;)

Comment: Yeah I have thought about this is it posiable to make an array of booleans?

Comment: @himmerz: I think you need a collection of doughnuts instead.

Comment: Sure, but you probably want an array of Doughnuts.

Comment: std::vector<Doughnut> Doughnuts;     ;)

Comment: @himmerz you have to buy me a chocolate doughnut now!!!)))

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a `Doughnut` class. Add a `boolean` member to the class and make a function that will allow you to change its value.

Answer (score 1):

If the Doughnut should disappear when eaten, do you really want a flag
at all?  It sounds to me more likely that you'd simply want to destruct
it.  Graphically, if you're using MVS, or something similar, the
visualization will be handled by an observer, and the destructor of the
Doughnut will inform the observer of its disappearance; the View object
will take care of the graphics (and probably destruct itself as well,
once the object has been erased from the screen).